# Is there a way to determine to which specific snapshot does an oplog slice belongs to in pbm list for mongo backups?

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, percona

I'm working on backup solutions for mongodb instances using percona backup manager.

When I do `pbm list` if the PITR option is enabled, I get the output for snapshot and oplog slice ranges.

Is there a way to determine which oplog slice range belongs to which backup from the output programmatically so that I can associate an oplog slice range to a snapshot.

Comment: hope this will help you https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-backup-mongodb/running.html

Comment: Nope. Already went through that :-)

Comment: As of version 1.4.0, only successfully completed backups are listed

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: Yes. But that's not what I was looking for. I was looking for it there is a way to associate an oplog slice to a backup snapshot. Version 1.4.1

Comment: ok for incremental please go through this https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-backup-mongodb/point-in-time-recovery.html

Comment: Time when back up start same time will show on PITR

Comment: I did that already. I went through all the docs but couldn't find if there is a way to say that this snapshot is the base point for this oplog slice range.

Comment: for example 2020-12-14T14:26:20Z [complete: 2020-12-14T14:34:39] for this backup PITR is 2020-12-14T14:26:40 - 2020-12-16T17:27:26

Comment: We can look at it and determine. But is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: if you want to restore then first restore **2020-12-14T14:26:20Z [complete: 2020-12-14T14:34:39]** then apply **2020-12-14T14:26:40 - 2020-12-16T17:27:26** this slice and you'll get data till **2020-12-16T17:27:26**

Comment: yes, Slice will always start **=>(greater than equal)** of full snapshot time and **<(less than)** next full snapshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233777/discussion-between-rohit-khurana-and-underoos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice always starts **=>(greater than equal)** of full snapshot time and **<(less than)** next full snapshot.

for example **2020-12-14T14:26:20Z [complete: 2020-12-14T14:34:39]** for this backup PITR(Slice) is **2020-12-14T14:26:40 - 2020-12-16T17:27:26**

if you want to restore then first **restore 2020-12-14T14:26:20Z [complete: 2020-12-14T14:34:39]** then **apply 2020-12-14T14:26:40 - 2020-12-16T17:27:26** this slice and you'll get data till **2020-12-16T17:27:26**

You can get more details here https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-backup-mongodb/point-in-time-recovery.html